# socket is not defined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('startNot', function (data) {
        if (runing == 0) setupNote(data);
        else socket.emit('redToStart',{ runing: 1 });
    });
});
```

I develop app in node.js and i have problem, code crashes when it reaches here

```
else socket.emit('redToStart',{ runing: 1 });
```

trowed this error

```
    socket.emit('redToStart',{ runing: 0 });
    ^
ReferenceError: socket is not defined
```

I try change code like this.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var socket = socket;
    socket.on('startNot', function (data) {
        if (runing == 0) setupNote(data);
        else socket.emit('redToStart',{ runing: 1 });
    });
});
```

but this code doesn't work too,any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not on the code posted.

It is on this line (notice the runing: 0 and not 1):

```
socket.emit('redToStart',{ runing: 0 });
```

which is probably outside

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
```

where the socket is defined

Comment: i need emit to socket,how to do that? define 
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { again?

Comment: No, you have to put it inside the existing one.

Comment: I did so,now i have another problem,in my code i have socket.emit(which is inside io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {... ) but socket not emitet,i dont know why,no errors,no warnings,console.log in that line works fine(and after too)

Comment: please start another question for your problem and be sure to include all the relevant code!